# How to update Secret Token property in Azure AD Synchronization API?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to find a way how to **programmatically change properties of Enterprise Application (non-catalogue app), specifically Secret Token and Tenant ULR in 'Provisioning' blade**, allowing to synchronize user/group objects between AAD and an external app (e.g. SaaS app) that supports it.

My customer has a strict policy to rotate all secrets and keys in Azure in regular intervals, so they want to be able to have an automation runbook that would change that token in the app (it is actually an Azure Databricks instance that supports this sync) as well as in AAD.

I checked whether there was a direct PowerShell support but I couldn’t find a specific cmdlet for this scenario (tried both GA and preview versions of AAD PowerShell 2.0).

I found a good documentation page describing AAD Synchronization API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/synchronization-overview?view=graph-rest-beta – however, I am unable to find, how to update the Secret Token property.

Ideally, I would like to see a code sample of a REST call on how change that specific property using Synchronization API. A PowerShell example would be even better. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it for non-gallery SCIM apps:

PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/99abefe8-3ad8-488f-b14f-df209cbc1ab3/synchronization/secrets

```
{ 
    value: [ 
        { key: "BaseAddress", value: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
        { key: "SecretToken", value: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
     ]
}
```

Replace the GUID after servicePrincipals with your real servicePrincipal object ID.

For apps that aren't non-gallery SCIM apps, the credential names required can be discovered in the metadata -> configurationFields part of the synchronizationTemplate object:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/synchronization-synchronizationtemplate?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Thank you, Aaron, for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I relalize this issue is over 4 years old, but I recently needed a similar solution for a Gallery Enterprise Application. I found the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-serviceprincipal-put-synchronization?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) documentation helpful.

Here is my solution with PowerShell:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Synchronization.Read.All",  "Synchronization.ReadWrite.All"
    
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications
    
$servicePrincipalId = Get-MgServicePrincipal | Where-Object -Property DisplayName -EQ '[Name of Enterprise App]' | Select -ExpandProperty Id
$secretToken = "[Secret Token]"
    
$params = @"
{
    "value": [
        {
            "key": "BaseAddress",
            "value": "[]"
        },
        {
            "key": "SecretToken",
            "value": "$secretToken"
        },
        {
            "key": "SyncNotificationSettings",
            "value": "{\"Enabled\":false,\"DeleteThresholdEnabled\":false}"
        },
        {
            "key": "SyncAll",
            "value": "false"
        }
    ]
}
"@ 
    
Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method PUT -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$servicePrincipalId/synchronization/secrets -ContentType application/json -Body $params
```